# Query SQl Server 2005 Full Text Search noise/stop words

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, stop-words, noise-words

Is it possible to get the list of Full Text Search noise/stop words from SQL Server 2005 by querying the database?

I am aware that the noise words are in a text file ~/FTData/noiseEng.txt but this file is not accessible to our application.

I've look at the sys.fulltext_* tables but these don't seem to have the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible in SQL 2005 but is in SQL Server 2008.

[Advanced Queries for Using SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search StopWords / StopLists](http://arcanecode.com/2008/06/03/advanced-queries-for-using-sql-server-2008-full-text-search-stopwords-stoplists/)

> This next query gets a list of all of
>   the stopwords that ship with SQL
>   Server 2008. This is a nice
>   improvement, you can not do this in
>   SQL Server 2005.

[Stopwords and Stoplists - SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

> SQL Server 2005 noise words have been
>   replaced by stopwords. When a database
>   is upgraded to SQL Server 2008 from a
>   previous release, the noise-word files
>   are no longer used in SQL Server 2008.
>   However, the noise-word files are
>   stored in the FTDATA\
>   FTNoiseThesaurusBak folder, and you
>   can use them later when updating or
>   building the corresponding SQL Server
>   2008 stoplists. For information about
>   upgrading noise-word files to
>   stoplists, see Full-Text Search
>   Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy the noise words file from `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData` into my app, and use it to strip noise words.

```
    Public Function StripNoiseWords(ByVal s As String) As String
        Dim NoiseWords As String = ReadFile("/Standard/Core/Config/noiseENU.txt").Trim
        Dim NoiseWordsRegex As String = Regex.Replace(NoiseWords, "\s+", "|") ' about|after|all|also etc.
        NoiseWordsRegex = String.Format("\s?\b(?:{0})\b\s?", NoiseWordsRegex)
        Dim Result As String = Regex.Replace(s, NoiseWordsRegex, " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ' replace each noise word with a space
        Result = Regex.Replace(Result, "\s+", " ") ' eliminate any multiple spaces
        Return Result
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi Herb, this could work but our app runs on clients servers that are usually locked down so access to the file is restricted. Getting clients to copy & paste the noise words wouldn't have been an acceptable solution unfortunately